# Fundamental theorem of vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$ some questions to understand it better

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Attached, a screenshoot from the book "The geometry of physics" by Theodore Frankel

[image]

I would like to better understand what the theorem means.

- First question : Did they forgot in the theorem to say that $\Phi(0,q)=q$ ?
- Second question : Here we say it is possible to find a flow starting
  in a neighborhood of $p$ where the vector field represent the
  velocity of this flow. But why only on a neighborhood ? As we work in
  $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the vector field is $C^k$ in $U$, could'nt we
  start a flow anywhere in $U$ ? If would like a visual example
  illustrating that what I say is not true in general if possible.
- Third question : I am not sure to understand the english of the
  sentence "Any two such curves are equal on the intersection of their
  t-domaines ("uniqueness")" in the second paragraph. Do they mean that
  if two curves cut then they are identical (because of the first order
  differential equation).
- Last question : I am not sure to understand the last paragraph (maybe
  because of english or because of my math comprehension I don't know).
  Do they mean the following thing : the ensemble of curves $\{
     \phi_t\}$ is not a group because with $\epsilon=1/2$ : $\phi_{1/2}$
  belongs to the ensemble but $\phi_{1/2} \circ \phi_{1/2}$ not (the
  law is not "closed"). In fact that is the final sentence that I don't understand "the point is that $\phi_{1/2}(q)$ need not be in the set $U_p$ on which $\phi_{1/2}$ is defined".

Comment: First question (The one concerning $\Phi(0,q)=q$ is nothing more than the definition of _flux_... try to look if in the previous pages if there's such a defintion.

Comment: @ErikPillon yes I agree but as they didn't said it in the hypothesis of the theorem I wanted to check. But I'm ok with that thanks

Comment: In a minute I will work at the solution...